# Does ElasticSearch Snapshot/Restore functionality cause the data to be analyzed again during restore?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a decent amount of data in my ElasticSearch index. I changed the `default analyzer` for the index and hence essentially I need to reindex my data so that it is analyzed again using the new analyzer. So instead of creating a test script that will delete all of the existing data in the ES index and re-add the data I thought if there is a back-up/restore module that I could use. As part of that, I found the snapshot/restore module that ES supports - [ElasticSearch-SnapshotAndRestore](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html).

My question is - If I use the above ES snapshot/restore module will it actually cause the data to be re-analyzed? Since I changed the default analyzer, I need the data to be reanalyzed. If not, is there an alternate tool/module you will suggest that will allow for pure export and import of data and hence cause the data to be re-analyzed during import?

DevUser

Answer (score 1):

No it does not re-analyze the data. You will need to reindex your data.

Fortunately that's fairly straightforward with Elasticsearch as it by default stores the source of your documents:

> **Reindexing your data**
>
> While you can add new types to an index, or add new fields to a type,
>   you can’t add new analyzers or make changes to existing fields. If you
>   were to do so, the data that has already been indexed would be
>   incorrect and your searches would no longer work as expected.
>
> The simplest way to apply these changes to your existing data is just
>   to reindex: create a new index with the new settings and copy all of
>   your documents from the old index to the new index.
>
> One of the advantages of the _source field is that you already have
>   the whole document available to you in Elasticsearch itself. You don’t
>   have to rebuild your index from the database, which is usually much
>   slower.
>
> To reindex all of the documents from the old index efficiently, use
>   scan & scroll to retrieve batches of documents from the old index, and
>   the bulk API to push them into the new index.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/reindex.html

I'd read up on Scan and Scroll prior to taking this approach:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html

TaskRabbit did opensource an import/export tool but I've not used it so cannot recommend but it is worth a look:

https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump